# Sloppy English?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, translation, spanish

I just read a post by a non-native English teacher whose title reads like this:

> "Never is late: Nunca es tarde para aprender".

Unfortunately, it frequently happens that a Spanish teacher makes this sort of literal translation, and I am quite sure this is one of those cases. However, I would appreciate it if someone could confirm.

Some more context: the Spanish sentence coming after "Never is late" would translate as "It is never late to learn". The post is all about the teacher's experience teaching English, and it has absolutely nothing to do with explaining grammatical structures or referring to the title of some type of artwork.

Comment: Hello, Sarah. 'Never is Late' is a title of something or other (you can look it up). The post may alternatively be looking at 'John never is late' vs 'John is never late' variants. Either would license the title. But without a lot more context, how can one decide whether the title is acceptable?

Comment: Include the Spanish sentence. There are many Spanish speakers who are bi-lingual.

Comment: Please give the entire sentence, both Spanish and English, and maybe even the sentences before and after. Otherwise, just 'never is late' is simply ungrammatical and incomprehensible English and we can't determine what was intended.

Comment: So I take it that your question is, 'Does "Never is late" work as a meaningful expression in idiomatic English, or is it a confusing and almost incoherent mangling of the usual idiomatc phrase "It's never too late"?'

Comment: All right, Mari-Lou A, I am aware that many Spanish speakers are bilingual. I was purposely seeking English native speakers' opinions. I just included the Spanish sentence, anyway.

Comment: Sven Yargs, that is exactly my question. Thank you.

Comment: Mitch, there is no previous sentence, I gave you the heading. The first two sentences of the post are "Hello, my name is Mar. I'm an English teacher at a Cambridge certified language school".

Comment: Your translation is correct. Not sure how a user/answerer could expand further on this. You need to incorporate Sven Yarg's clarification, discreet and clever man that he is, he's helping you to make the question "on-topic"

Comment: Isn't the subject dropped in the Spanish? *[Eso] nunca es tarde para aprender.*

Comment: Laurel, no, it isn't. There's nothing wrong at all with the Spanish sentence.